# Permission denied when I tried to incorporate node to my terminal on texteditor

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I just installed node.js and npm, whenever I tried to run them on my texteditor (I use VSC), the permission is always denied. I was told to open the terminal (on my texteditor) and drag + drop the js. files I’m working on and then add "node" + press "enter" to make them run, but the permission is always denied. please help. heres the image [node denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU9Gv.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod 755 foldername
```

Enable execute permission for that folder

https://www.macinstruct.com/node/415